# eval in parent frame and current frame

Tags: r

I am looking for an elegant (and safe!) way to evaluate an amended call in the parent frame. By "amended" I mean I modified the call in such a way that it refers to something not included in parent frame but in another frame. I guess one could also say: "send something up but only for evaluation".

It is clarified what I want by the example below which works in some circumstances, but not all. The `update` function (`stats:::update.default`) uses `eval` and I added the `weights` argument with something (`res`) that is not in the same environment as the evaluation takes place. So I used `get("res", pos = -1L)` and I hope it is a safe way to refer to the environment `res` lives in. For models estimated with a variable as formula, both defined methods fail:

```
mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
form <- mpg ~ cyl
mod2 <- lm(form, data = mtcars)

wls1 <- function(x) {
  res <- residuals(x)^2 # example
  result <- update(x, weights = 1/get("res", pos = -1L))
  return(result)
}

wls2 <- function(x) {
  res <- residuals(x)^2 # example
  result <- update(x, weights = 1/res)
  return(result)
}

wls3 <- function(x) {
  data(ChickWeight)
  ChickWeight$cyl <- ChickWeight$weight
  ChickWeight$mpg <- ChickWeight$Time
  result <- update(x, data = ChickWeight)
  return(result)
}

wls1(mod)   # works
wls1(mod2)  # errors
wls2(mod)   # works
wls2(mod2)  # erros

wls3(mod)   # works
wls3(mod2)  # works
```

How can this be solved in general in a safe way?
I was looking for a function that gives the current environment (something like a fictious `this.environment()` function) so avoid the `pos` argument and use the `envir` of `get` (I know I can create my own temporary environment and have `res` associated to it to use something like `envir = my.eny`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by creating a `quote`d 'language' object for the formula and then update the `call` of the model

```
form <- quote(mpg ~ cyl)
wlsN <- function(x, formula) {
   x$call$formula <- formula
   res <- residuals(x)^2 
   update(x, weights = 1/res)  # it is in the same environment.  No need for get 
 }


wlsN(mod2, form)
#Call:
#lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, weights = 1/res)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          cyl  
#     37.705       -2.841
```

-checking with other formula

```
form1 <- quote(disp ~ cyl + vs)
form2 <- quote(mpq ~ gear + carb)

mod1 <- lm(form1, data = mtcars)
mod2 <- lm(form2, data = mtcars)
wlsN(mod1, form1) # works
wlsN(mod2, form2) # works
```

Comment: Sure. However, this feels somehow working around it. I am looking for something more general (I don't want to check which elements are offending...). Isn't my original code supposed to work?

Comment: @Helix123  It is general.  I am not checking elements, just replacing the formula in the call.  If you check the `call` without changing it would be the `form` instead of `mpg ~ cyl` and that is creating the issue

Comment: Ok, let's say 'without prior knowledge' then.

Comment: @Helix123  You create any formula and pass it assuming that the column exist in the dataset.  I don't know what kind of generalization you are opting for?

Comment: @Helix123  Check the updated post.  What do you meant by without prior knowledge?  Do you want to automatically parse the formula without any knowlege.  If you don't pass the `formula`, there is a clash in the `call`

Comment: The clash in the call seems to stem from the fact that 'form' is defined in the global env while the `eval` happens elsewhere. I am looking for way to have both evaluate/accessed at the right spot. Or is this a bug in `stats:::update.default`? See my `wls3` where I modify the `data` arg and that one works (adding an arg errors) [I know there is also `<<-` to have a variable assigned to the global environment but it is dangerous as it overwrites a variable with a same name there]

Comment: @Helix123  Anyway all your examples work with simply passing the `formula` as argument\

Comment: Sure. It is just that I am more interested in the `eval`-ism involveld than in the example at hand...

Comment: @Helix123  Sorry, I can't read all that is in your mind.  I answered the question based on the facts provided

Comment: Thank you Arun, for the prompt support. I thought I expressed what I am interested in the very first paragraph of the question.

Comment: Try debug(model.frame) and look at how it determines the environment to evaluate the extra arguments in.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to work around the fact that R looks for the value of weights in either `data` or the environment of the `formula` - which in the case of the variable named `form` in your example, is the global environment.

An alternative that riffs on the same theme as [akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697612/7050789) answer:

```
wls3 <- function(x) {
 environment(x$call$formula) <- environment()
 res <- residuals(x)^2
 result <- update(x, weights=1/res)
}
```

I can see how this could get ugly in less trivial uses of this workaround such as when the formula of `x` already has an environment that does not enclose (potentially wrong use of the term) the environment in the call to `wls3()`.

Another alternative (not recommended) is to use assign, e.g.

```
wls4 <- function(x) {
 assign('res', residuals(x)^2, envir=environment(formula(x)))
 result <- update(x, weights=1/res)
}
```

however this has the unintended consequence of leaving the variable `res` in the global environment.

Comment: I think the more important drawback of `wls4` is that a variable named that exists in global environment prior gets overwritten (sure, one can test for that an find a different name but looping over e.g. res1, ... resN).

Comment: Than you for your take on that! I was wondering if there is no way to address an environment more directly (via an absolute address) in a solution featureing `get("res", envir = <absolute_address>` such that `eval` knows where to find `res`.

Comment: Oh, wow, seems like the same issue popped up on r-devel independently these days: https://hypatia.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-August/076548.html - let's see what happens.

Comment: Not surprising it came up on r-devel, too, but what timing! I suppose another take is to add an argument to `wls` which takes an environment that the user wants to place residuals in - so the user has control over the environment for `form` and `res`. Regarding `get`; you would still need to provide (now as an argument to `get`) something that is visible in the environment of `form` - so you're stuck with the same problem as before (I thoroughly recommend you try `debug(model.frame)` and see where it falls over with your examples). Happy travels!